# Writing a fail2ban multiline regex

Tags: linux, fail2ban

I'm not sure if this the correct regex, but i'm trying to add multiple lines at the ignoreregex

Here are the config lines in my ddos.conf:

```
[Definition]
failregex = ^<HOST> -.*"(GET|POST).*
ignoreregex =.*(robots.txt|favicon.ico|jpg|png)
             ^<HOST> -.*"(GET|POST).*(Googlebot|bingbot)
```

Is the code is correct what should i add to multiply lines

Answer (score 0):

You can add multiple regexs to `failregex` and `ignoreregex` (exactly in the same way you did it by `ignoreregex`), just:

- `ignoreregex` doesn't really expect tag `<HOST>`, so either replace it with `\S+` or something similar;
- your regexs are vulnerable - don't use catch-all's (`.*`, `.+`, etc), so always try to write a regex as precise as possible and anchor it. For example due to first `ignoreregex` and attacker could add `?robots.txt` to the request to ignore finding.
- the same way a fake googlebot can continue its attack - it is not enough to check the agent only.

> Writing a fail2ban multiline regex

As regards the multiline regex possibility - it depends on how the log does look and what exactly you need to parse from there, so it is hardly possible to describe without an example.

See my answer to similar question at [github.com / fail2ban #2971, comment-798429044](https://github.com/fail2ban/fail2ban/issues/2971#issuecomment-798429044).

Also note my answer in [stackoverflow / 64857401 #65375323](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64857401/create-a-cakephp-filter-for-fail2ban/65375323#65375323).